# What is the 2D shape that gives the maximum finite volume of a solid of revolution?

Tags: volume, solid-of-revolution

What is the 2D shape that gives the maximum finite volume of a solid of revolution?

The following image (inspired by the one at [Weisstein, Eric W. "Pappus's Centroid Theorem." From *MathWorld*--A Wolfram Web Resource.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html)) shows a right triangle, a rectangle and a semicircle; all three of them have area equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}R^2$.

The horizontal coordinate of the centroid is $\frac{R}{3}$ for the right triangle, $\frac{R}{2}$ for the rectangle and $\frac{4}{3}\frac{R}{\pi}$ for the semicircle.

The volumes are $\frac{1}{3}\pi^2R^3$ for the cone, $\frac{1}{2}\pi^2R^3$ for the cylinder and $\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3$ for the sphere and so the cylinder has the maximum volume; so, is the rectangle the lamina that, when rotated, gives the maximum volume?

[image]

Comment: a square with the same area will give more volume.

Comment: You want the most area *as far from the axis as possible* (of course).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I am sorry but I do not understand your comment.